# When I modify a JPanel after it becomes visible, paintComponent gets called before componentResized

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a data plot with a color bar that's a `JPanel` with a layout that has two `JPanel`s inside of it. One `JPanel` is the data plot itself, and the other is the color bar. I'd like to add functionality so the color bar can be toggled on and off, and I've gone about this by simply removing the `JPanel` containing the color bar. Something like this:

```
public class Data2DPlotWithColorBar extends JPanel {
    public Data2DPlotWithColorBar() { 
        this.data2DPlot = new Data2DPlot();
        this.colorBar  = new VerticalColorBar();
        this.setPlot();
    }

    public final void toggleColorBar() {
        enableColorBar = !enableColorBar;
        setPlot();
    }

    private void setPlot() {                
        this.removeAll();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        if (enableColorBar) {
            this.add(colorBar, BorderLayout.EAST);
        }
        this.add(this.data2DPlot, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    private final Data2DPlot data2DPlot;    
    private final VerticalColorBar colorBar;
    private boolean enableColorBar;
}
```

The problem is that when the color bar is removed, the data plot has a component listener with the `componentResized` method overrided which correctly resizes the data (maintains fixed aspect ratio) to fit the size of the JPanel. Something like this:

```
public class Data2DPlot extends JPanel { 

    ...

    @Override
    public final void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        double scaleFactorBuf = Math.min((double)getPixelMaxViewWidth()/getNativeWidth(), 
                                         (double)getPixelMaxViewHeight()/getNativeHeight());    
        // Make sure scaleFactorBuf isn't close to zero
        if (Math.abs(scaleFactorBuf) > MathUtilities.LAMBDA) {
            scaleFactor = scaleFactorBuf;
        }
    }


    ...   


    @Override
    protected final void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  
        ....
    }  

}
```

It turns out that as-is, the dataplot is not resizing properly. I did some debugging and I found out that `componentResized` gets called AFTER the `paintComponent` method when I toggle the color bar off and on. This means the image gets painted, and then the `scaleFactor` gets updated afterwards, which is incorrect. The only way I've been able to fix it so far is to call `repaint()` at the very end of the `componentResized` method. However, `repaint()` is already called when the component is resized, so I feel like this is the incorrect approach. Some googled led me to solutions involving the use of `revalidate` and `repaint` after modifying a `JPanel` on demand. However, any combination of doing this still led to `componentResized` being called after `repaint`. Is there a standard fix for this?

Comment: Yours appears to be a complex set up, making it difficult to fully understand with code snippets and brief explanations. We don't want to see the whole program, but if you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Beware, `componentResized` may be called multiple times in quick succession, such as when the window is resized.  What I've done in the past is used a `javax.swing.Timer`, set to non-repeating and using a small delay (~100ms) which gets restarted each time `componentResized` is called.  This stops the timer from trigger an update until 100ms has passed.  Once triggered, I perform the updates I need and call `repaint`...Another solution is to override `invalidate` and reset the buffer (to `null`) and use `paintComponent` to rebuild the buffer when it's called (while the buffer is `null`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right now the main problem is the order in which it's called. I need `componentResized` to be called before `paintComponent`. For some reason, with my above setup, `componentResized` gets called at the very end, after `paintComponent`. I'll try to get a complete example up in a bit.

Comment: You change the order in which these events occur.  It is likely the the `JPanel` is also responding to the change size and it or another part of the framework is publishing a repaint event. The only thing you can do is work within the current work flow

Answer (score 1):

An answer proposed in [this thread](https://coderanch.com/t/601266/java/Repainting-JPanel-componentResized-event) offers an easy solution; rather than overriding the componentResized method, do the setBounds(int,int,int,int) one.

The call order of componentResized, setBounds, and repaint is strange; on program startup it is like this;

- setBounds
- componentResized
- repaint

while if you manually resize it later (I did not test with in-code resizing order) it goes

- setBounds
- repaint
- componentResized

By setting your flags in setBounds rather than componentResized, you can know to recompute your repaint size-sensitive variables on panel resizing, effective immediately.